# .env with create-react-app can't pass apikey

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I was using .env before in react and there was no issue of passing api-keys but now the situation is a little bit tricky and I need to declare api-key like that

```
const instance = axios.create({
withCredentials: true,
baseURL: "https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/",
headers: {
    "API-KEY": "API-KEY-GO-HERE"
}
});
```

so basically its object.
I read about .env and as I understand I can't pass an object in .env style.

When I try to pass the API-KEY like that it doesn't work.
It's my Base.js file

```
export const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
```

Here is my api.js file

```
import {API_KEY} from "./base";

const instance = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: "https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/",
    headers: {
        "API-KEY": API_KEY
    }
});
```

Don't work for me.

Any ideas of how I can pass .env correctly to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was only in restarting react-app. Without restarting variables in `.env` file don't update.

This part of code is working example

```
import {API_KEY} from "./base";

const instance = axios.create({
withCredentials: true,
baseURL: "https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/",
headers: {
    "API-KEY": API_KEY
}
});
```